# BASH in Android > using wildcards doesn't work

Tags: android, bash, notifications, pattern-matching, wildcard

I'm attempting to track the deactivation of notifications within android.
This I planned on doing by polling the notification dumpsys every x seconds.
There for I've put the notification into a variable so I can search the $tmp variable for a text (in this case google.gm) and based on this it will set the $Gmail on true or false.

When I tested my script-setup via Cygwin terminal on the PC it worked great, however not on Android

getting the dumpsys notification into $tmp works fine, but when I test it (in the shell) on android it seems to not want to accept my * wildcards.

```
tmp=$(dumpsys notification)
[[ "$tmp" == *"google.gm"* ]] && Gmail=true || Gmail=false
```

I've been searching the web for the last two hours, but It'd kinda driving me crazy.
I've done simplified tests to debug it and it really seems to be in the wildcard character

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

After the new suggestions I managed to make this out of it:

```
tmp=$(dumpsys notification)
case $tmp in *notify_missed_call*) PRF1="1" ;; *) PRF1="0" ;; esac
case $tmp in *conv_notify*) PRF2="1" ;; *) PRF2="0" ;; esac
case $tmp in *NotYetThere*) PRF3="1" ;; *) PRF3="0" ;; esac
case $tmp in *stat_notify_calendar*) PRF4="1" ;; *) PRF4="0" ;; esac
echo $PRF1,$PRF2,$PRF3,$PRF4, > /sdcard/tmp.txt
```

But somehow it only works when put in 1 line with ; between them.
any way to make this work multiline (easier to maintain) and optimize it?

thanks

Comment: there's no wildcards in your example?

Comment: Unless you use a modified Android image, Androids default installation does not use bash. There are many things, aside wildcards (which mostly actually do), which don't work in it (like `[[`). You better get a Busybox or real Bash on it.

Comment: Sorry about that,forgot it has been rooted from day 1. It has busybox installed :)

Comment: it is the code.. wildcards being the *

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting false positives (Gmail set to true when it shouldn't) or false negatives (Gmail set to false when it shouldn't)? What is a typical value for `tmp` when Gmail is set incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you just `grep` for `google.gm`?

Comment: @Nixx, so it has busybox ash? that's not bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have bash on that Android, so try using POSIX instead.

```
case $(dumpsys notification) in 
    *google.gm*) Gmail=true ;;
    *) Gmail=false ;;
esac
```

**Update**
Given your updated answer, I see you're checking for multiple values in the output of `dumpsys notification`. Assuming only one of those strings can occur in a line, a better way of doing that is to read it line by line with the shell or awk

```
dumpsys notification | { 
    while read -r line; do
        case $line in
            *notify_missed_call*) prf1=1;;
            *conv_notify*) prf2=1;;
            *NotYetThere*) prf3=1;;
            *stat_notify_calendar*) prf4=1;;
        esac
    done
    echo "${prf1:-0},${prf2:-0},${prf3:-0},${prf4:-0}"
} > /sdcard/tmp.txt
```

With awk, you can detect multiple values in the same line.

```
dumpsys notification | awk '
    /notify_missed_call/{missed=1}
    /conv_notify/{conv=1}
    /NotYetThere/{notyet=1}
    /stat_notify_calendar/{cal=1}
    END { print missed+0,conv+0,notyet+0,cal+0 }' > /sdcard/tmp.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything in the shell.

I've got BusyBox v1.18.4 installed and have other scripts working, just not this one :)

Comment: @Nixx, doesn't do anything? It doesn't set the Gmail variable to true or false based on the output of `dumpsys`? the variable remains empty? does it produce an error message? Btw, yet another way to test the output is  `if dumpsys notification | grep -Fq 'google.gm'; then Gmail=true; else Gmail=false; fi`

Comment: Sorry about the "doing nothing" I was still asleep at the moment of writing and didn't echo the $Gmail to check... 
but in both sitution I get a false back eventhough their is a android.google.gm present in the dumpsys notification

Comment: okay, have double checked it when awake, and it's the right answer :)
thank you for helping out!

Comment: mmh, those look interesting, but both five an error back:
the first on in the first line : Unexpected token
the second one in line 3: Syntax error: expecting "in"

I just copy-paste yours in a .sh to see if they work.

Comment: @Nixx, tested them here with dash, no syntax errors. So either the busybox shell is not posix compliant, or perhaps your editor added dos line endings (CRLF instead of LF).

Comment: I've added another question here on stackoverflow, hope you'll be able to help me with that too.
If possible it would be great to have a suggestion on how to get the AWK values into $variables as can't make those compatible somehow.
thanks!